# how to get access from local machine to server-side terminal by using node

Tags: terminal

I want to get access to server-side terminal from node js code(from my local machine ) . I know that if you want to execute some terminal commands from code ( from node js code) , u can use `child-process` - but how to make connection to server-side terminal and send some commands there . Hope my question is clear .

Answer (score 0):

If SSH is enabled in your server, you can use the [NPM node-ssh package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh)

```
var path, node_ssh, ssh, fs

fs = require('fs')
path = require('path')
node_ssh = require('node-ssh')
ssh = new node_ssh()

ssh.connect({
  host: 'localhost',
  username: 'steel',
  privateKey: '/home/steel/.ssh/id_rsa'
}).then( function(){
    /* your ssh interactions with the server go here */
    /* use the node-ssh API to execute commands, upload files... */ 
})
```

Comment: yes, I also found this library `https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh` . How can I send this line from your example `/campaign/mcd/mcd-cmd.sh localhost 54322 "mcd campaign create" /campaign/9338a0ba-6f4d-404d-b792-05d3d161d7a7.json` <--- here you can see command which I need to execute

Comment: Read the API documentation, you will find there, all the details you need.